# Firebase multi filter query in flutter

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

So I have a query that I use for FirebaseAnimatedList
`Query query = ref.orderByChild("userid").equalTo(user.uid);`
It gives me a list filter by what I wanted.
But how do I filtered from the query based on what I input?
Basically, how do I allow it to have a multi filter?

Comment: Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property. For an example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Comment: how about you use `if` statement to filter based on your input?

Comment: Somehow i wish they implement a function for multi filter

Answer (score 0):

The "multi filter" query that you're looking for in Firebase Realtime Database is one of its limitations, but there's a workaround for this as mentioned by Puf in the comments. If you're just starting out, it's worth looking into [Cloud Firestore](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore) as it can handle advanced queries better.